# Trying to output a custom powershell object where I can align each line of two different variables containing Category:Description

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, scripting, active-directory

I'm trying to do an network access control audit by grabbing a user's AD groups, their descriptions and then output them in a way shown by this example:

---

> ### [User]
>
> @[1]Groups : @[1]GroupDescription
> @[2]...
> @[3]...

---

Below is what I have at the moment.

```
$UserGroups = @{

User = Read-Host -Prompt "What user do You want to look up Access for?"
Groups = (Get-ADUser $User -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
GroupsDescriptions = (Get-ADUser $User -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | % {(Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties *).description}
}

$Object = New-Object psobject -Property $UserGroups

$Object | format-table | Export-Csv c:\tmp\test.csv
```

Though the output is very strange. I don't understand it. Below is a result of Get-Content C:tmp\test.csv

> #TYPE Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
> "ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd","pageHeaderEntry","pageFooterEntry","autosizeInfo","shapeInfo","groupingEntry"
> "033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280",,,,"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo",
> "9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3",,,,,
> "27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,
> "4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df",,,,,
> "cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c",,,,,

I have tried outputting to a .txt file using Out-file, but I always get each property cut off with a ... at the end. I've used the -Autosize and -Expand when formatting the data before piping it to the export line.

Any Suggestions or advice would be extremely helpful.

Things I'll be Looking at later
[Go through each line in PowerShell object and extract variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53770025/go-through-each-line-in-powershell-object-and-extract-variables)
[Powershell & ActiveDirectory - trying to output users in a group and their membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285921/powershell-activedirectory-trying-to-output-users-in-a-group-and-their-membe)
[Out-file crops my text when trying to output a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684658/out-file-crops-my-text-when-trying-to-output-a-table)
Thanks!

Comment: Remove `| format-table` from the last line. `Format-Table` is exclusively used for display output to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As stated, **only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to produce *for-display* output**, never for outputting *data* that must be processed programmatically later. What `Format-Table` outputs are objects representing *formatting instructions*, and it is *their* properties that ended up in your CSV file - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375) for more information.
- In **order to include *collections* (arrays) in CSV output, you must convert them to a *single string***, using a self-chosen separator. Otherwise, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) simply calls `.ToString()` on the *collection object itself*, which yields the collection's *type name*, and no information about its elements.

Therefore, use something like the following, which uses `', '` as the separator string to represent the group names and descriptions in a single column each:

```
$UserGroups = [pscustomobject] @{
  User = ($user = Read-Host -Prompt "What user do You want to look up Access for?")
  Groups = ($groups = (Get-ADUser $User -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf) -join ', '
  GroupsDescriptions = (
      $groups | ForEach-Object { (Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties *).Description }
    ) -join ', '
}

$UserGroups | Export-Csv c:\tmp\test.csv
```

Note:

- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is used to *directly* construct a  custom object, which is syntactic sugar available since PowerShell v3 that is simpler and more efficient than a [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object) call.
- In order to use the result from your `Read-Host` call in later properties of your object definition, you must cache it in aux. variable `$user` (note that enclosing the assignment in `(...)` passes its value through.
- Similarly, the result of the `Get-ADUser` call is cached in aux. variable `$groups`, so that it doesn't have to be repeated in the `GroupsDescriptions` value.
- However, as [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, it may be cleaner to make the `$user = ...` and `$groups = ...` assignments separate statements and place them *before* the object construction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you pipe to `Format-Table` before you pipe to `Export-Csv`. Only use `Format-Table` for displaying things on screen. The fix is to just remove that.

```
$Object | Export-Csv c:\tmp\test.csv
```

Comment: When I do this Only the user comes back properly, under groups is Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection
and under GroupsDescriptions is
System.Object[]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133898/powershell-pscustomobject-format-table-new-row-instead-of-one-line) and mklement0. I was able to figure out the formatting portion of this problem.

Now I have the remaining code that exports it exactly as intended.

```
$user= Read-Host -Prompt "What user bonehead?"
$object =  Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user

$Table = $object | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        Groups = $_.Name
        GroupDesc = (Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties *).Description
        GroupOwner = (Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties *).Info
        }
    }
    

$Table | Export-csv -NoTypeInformation c:\tmp\test.csv
```

The -NoTypeInformation helps eliminate the header on the .csv files and the piped Group info through the ForEach-Object cmdlet helped insure every object had it's own row in excel.